# Should a logo be a separate image in a html email?

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, spam-prevention

I'm probably thinking about this too much. I'm creating an HTML5 Email template and the logo sits just above the hero image which has a white background.  Should a logo be in a separate image than the hero image?

I'm wondering what the pros/cons of both would be in terms of performance & spam filtering.

My thoughts are that...

- With one image to load rather than two the performance will be improved.
- With only one alt tag and a larger image the email client may be more likely to consider it as SPAM as there is more content in the email which it can't read.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you're overthinking this! ;)

There is no difference in the marking as Spam between the both options. Also the loading time is likely insignificant, since the larger image takes almost as long as two smaller images.

One upside with images combined you would save some code and you will get your spacing exactly right.

A Downside would be that in Mobile Clients the Heroimage would scale down, but with the Logo attached to it, the Logo would scale down too. You might not want to have a Logo this small in Mobile.

Also one more thing: keep in mind that SO is for asking questions about coding, this could get flaged as off topic

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making the logo a separate image from the hero image. There are no spam implications and the performance gain would be marginal at best.

Other pros in separate the logo image from hero image:

- The logo and hero can be different image types optimized for the content. Eg. a `.png` for the logo and `.jpg` for the hero.
- The logo and hero can be moved around and scaled independently as the display size changes.
- Email would be slightly more accessible since `alt` attributes can be more targeted and specific.